# Ranorex Javascript ExecuteScript

Tags: ranorex

I need to run a javascript function of the web page from ranorex.
So, I gave Add New Action -> User code and,
I wrote the following code in Recording1.UserCode.cs

```
    public void greet()
    {
        WebDocument webDocument = "/doc";
        webDocument.ExecuteScript("document.write('Hello World!');");
    }
```

When I play the recording I got the following error in report:

"No element found for path '/doc' within 10s."

What is missing?
Or what is the right way to do it?

Comment: the simple answer is your xPath to the webdocument in incorrect.  personally i usually like to track webdocuments by their domain.  but "/doc" leads to nothing is what's actually happening

Answer (score 3):

You question was answered in the following post.
http://www.ranorex.com/forum/ranorex-javascript-executescript-t4436.html